# How to add LAN and RS232 in yocto

Tags: arm, driver, yocto, imx6

I have generated an Image(fsl-imx-x11 distro) from yocto but it doesn't contains LAN and RS232 terminal.
I would like to know where I can find its packages?
Is it also added same as recipe creation?
do I also need to change dtsi file?

Comment: what do you mean by `LAN and RS232 terminal`?

Comment: @Nayfe LAN: Ethernet (1Gig) and serial port(rs232) so that one has access to the image via either of them.

Comment: We need more information about the context (ie your board) to help you.  Did you try Freescale community version [here](https://github.com/freescale/fsl-community-bsp-platform)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might actually need to do is **Pin Muxing** on the the Board whereby, you need to add appropriate muxing of pins to activate the LAN and RS232 on the board.

For this you need to look into the board's **Device Tree**.

1. Refer to the Board's Documentation for `Pin Muxing` or `Device Tree` sections.
2. Find the respective `.dtsi` file in your `$BUILD_DIR/tmp/work/<board-bsp>/arch/arm/boot/dts/`
3. within the file you might need to enable pins under the `&iomuxc{}` structure.
4. at the bottom of the file you need enable the `status` flag to `okay`.

   ```
     &eth{
          pin-ctrl="..',
          status = "okay"
     };
   ```

   5. You need to recompile the kernel:

      bitbake  -f -c compile; bitbake your kernel

   or create a new image

### Note

there is a sophisticated way of doing this by appending your Device Tree files in recipe and using `devtool` but for that you need to look into the Mega Manual